# Handle Missing attributes in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm, missing-data

I have a dataset of 2500 records. Each record has 100 attributes. The issue I'm facing is that many of these records have one (or multiple) attribute **values missing**. Since such records are large in number (around 800), I cannot afford to ignore these records. All my attributes are **numeric**. My target attribute is categorical. It has 6 possible classes. I plan to use **SVM classifier** for training purposes.

What approach should I use to handle missing attributes values?

Also my testing data contains missing attributes as well. How do I handle missing values in testing data?

Answer (score 3):

Since 800 instances in a dataset of 2500 is pretty high, removing them is perhaps indeed not the best option.

Since you are dealing with numeric attributes, a common technique is to find some general value that can be used for the missing data. Often the **mean** is chosen for these purposes.

sklearn offers a preprocessor that does this in [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)

An example of it:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit([[1, 2], [np.nan, 3], [7, 6]])
```

The best solution ofcourse, would be to ask a domain expert to fill in the missing values, but that's often not possible.